# Django REST Framework: how to use session-based authentication properly?

Tags: rest, session, authentication

I'm building a project with Python/Django 1.7.1 and the Django REST Framework.

I have two subdomains for the project:

- api.myproject.com
- www.myproject.com

The WWW-host contains the website on which users can login. The REST backend is located on the API-host.

I configured Django REST Framework like this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {   
    'PAGINATE_BY': 10,
    'PAGINATE_BY_PARAM': None,
    'MAX_PAGINATE_BY': 10,
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

In essence: I'm using session-based authentication for AJAX on the WWW-host and token-based authentication for an Android application.

Now here is the problem. A user that's logged in on the WWW-host can use the REST API on the API-host, because the session-authentication is enabled. On the WWW-host there is JavaScript running that's making API calls to the API-host. This works fine, but when a user is logged in to the WWW-host and then opens up a new tab and goes to the API-host, the user can just SEE the REST API and it's not my intention of doing this.

Is there anyway to not show the REST API on the API-host when a user is logged in on the WWW-host?

I configured the session cookie domain and CSRF cookie domain like this:

```
DOMAIN = 'myproject.com'
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.' + DOMAIN
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN
```

I modified this to:

```
DOMAIN = 'myproject.com'
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'www.' + DOMAIN
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN
```

But when trying this, the REST API is not available through session authentication when a user is logged in on the WWW-host, because the cookie is only set for the WWW-host...

Any tips for my problem? :-)

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,
K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically... my question is kind of stupid and you can solve this with implementing permissions as needed. Problem solved! :-)